# Just-Dice or some other Gambling API?

Tags: api, gambling

Is there a gambling site where they expose an API for it? I want to build an application that leverages a crypto/bitcoin gambling site's bank roll. Just-dice seems to have the biggest bank roll to take advantage of, has anything been built for something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[satoshidice.com](https://satoshidice.com/api) and [999dice.com](https://www.999dice.com/api/) have a huge API.

Answer (score 1):

celldice.com has an API over secure http, 
see this link for details

https://celldice.com/api.en.txt